# Unable to install my first android app in my mobile,installable in other mobiles

Tags: android

I also allowed install from other sources but it's not working
When I click on install it process begins and then shows app not installed

Comment: what is your device model?

Comment: redmi note 8pro

Answer (score 0):

Please check developer option is enable in that device

In the Developer options window, scroll down to find and enable USB debugging

Enable Install via Usb as well